# jQuery function issue - Space in URL string

Tags: html, jquery, string, smarty

I've got a custom video sharing website that uses a jQuery function to clean video tag slugs like that:

```
https://www.example.com/search/videos?search_query=mutli%20words%20tag
```

to:

```
https://www.example.com/search/videos?search_query=mutli+words+tag
```

jQuery function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".mtags").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var search = $(this).text();
    $("#search_query").val(search);
    $("#search_form").attr('action',relative+'/search/videos');
    $("#search_form").submit();
    return false;
});
```

HTML file (Tags List Under Video):

```
            <div class="m-t-10 overflow-hidden">
                {assign var='keywords' value=$video.keyword}
                {section name=i loop=$keywords}
                    {if $keywords[i] neq ''}<a class="mtags" href="{$relative}/search/videos?search_query={$keywords[i]}">{$keywords[i]}</a>{/if}
                {/section}                      
            </div>
```

The issue is:

I actually created a new tag structure more google friendly:

```
https://www.example.com/tags/multi+tag+words
```

But the jQuery function only works with the default search structure:

```
https://www.example.com/search/videos?search_query=multi+tag+words
```

So I am getting:

```
https://www.example.com/tags/multi%20tag%20words
```

Is there any way to make the jQuery function to work with my new tag structure?

I had a few attempts but I failed. I don't really know jQuery.

Hope my explanation is clear. I can provide more details if needed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The "jQuery function" just takes the text of the element, plops it in a field, sets where to post the field to, and submits the form. It doesn't actually do anything with `%20` or `+`; that's just a side effect. If you want the format you're looking for, just write it out in the link. I don't know what framework you're using, but if it uses JavaScript, it's just `$keywords[i].replace(/\s/g, '+')`. And remove the "jQuery function".

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] with only HTML; CSS and JavaScript using the `[<>]` snippet editor

Comment: @HereticMonkey It uses Smarty Framework so your solution is not working in the template file.

Comment: Yeah, it was a guess based on the information I had. You might need to do some thinking on your own to translate it to Smarty.